# Select 'string' from dual returns single character

Tags: oracle, hibernate, groovy

I have a very simple Groovy class where I'm just trying to select a String from an Oracle 11g database using a native SQL query through Hibernate 3.3.2 GA. It seems so simple and yet I can't make sense of the results I'm getting. Here is the code:

```
package serialize

import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration
import org.hibernate.transform.ToListResultTransformer

class SerializeDatabaseObjects {


    static main(args) {

        def sessionFactory = initHibernate()

        def session = sessionFactory.openSession()

        def tx
        def result

        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction()

             result = session
                .createSQLQuery("""Select 'Hello World!' from dual""")
                .setResultTransformer(ToListResultTransformer.INSTANCE) 
                .list()

            tx.commit()
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            if (tx!=null){ 
                tx.rollback() 
            }
            throw e
        }
        finally {
            session.close()
        }


        println result

        sessionFactory.close()
    }

    static initHibernate(){
        return new Configuration().configure().setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true").buildSessionFactory()
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Hibernate: Select 'Hello World!' from dual
[[H]]
```

The ToListResultTransformer was my latest attempt to get the entire `'Hello World!'` String to get printed but IMO shouldn't be needed. But no matter what I try 'H' is always the result.

How do I get the entire 'Hello World' string to be returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I was typing this question I figured out the answer. It appears that Hibernate is interpreting the result as a character instead of a String and therefore only returning 'H'.

The way I found to fix this is to add a column alias in the select statement and then use [addScalar(String columnAlias, Type type)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/api/org/hibernate/SQLQuery.html#addScalar%28java.lang.String,%20org.hibernate.type.Type%29)  to specify that the result should be interpreted as a String.

Again, I used a ResultTransformer([AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/api/org/hibernate/transform/AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.html)) so my result would contain the column name and it's contents but it is not strictly necessary.

If anyone would like to expand on why Hibernate is mapping the result as a character instead of a String or suggest an alternative(easier) way of forcing the result to be a string, please comment or post an answer.

Here is the code that produces the expected results:

```
package serialize

import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration
import org.hibernate.transform.AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer
import org.hibernate.type.StringType

class SerializeDatabaseObjects {


    static main(args) {

        def sessionFactory = initHibernate()

        def session = sessionFactory.openSession()

        def tx
        def result

        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction()

             result = session
                .createSQLQuery("""Select 'Hello World!' as hello from dual""")
                .addScalar("hello", new StringType())
                .setResultTransformer(AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE)
                .list()

            tx.commit()
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            if (tx!=null){ 
                tx.rollback() 
            }
            throw e
        }
        finally {
            session.close()
        }


        println result

        sessionFactory.close()
    }

    static initHibernate(){
        return new Configuration().configure().setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true").buildSessionFactory()
    }
}
```

And the output:

```
Hibernate: Select 'Hello World!' as hello from dual
[[hello:Hello World!]]
```